# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'on' Python-Django

Tags: python, django-views

i am learning django from official django tutorial. and i am getting this error when vote something from form. this caused from - probably - vote function under views.py

here is my views.py / vote function :

```
def vote(request,poll_id):
    p=get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
            selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
            return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {'poll':p,
                                                            'error_message' : "didint select anything ",}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))

    else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls.views.results', args=(p.id,)))
```

and this is error message screen :

> **ValueError at /polls/2/vote/
>
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'on'**
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   127.0.0.1:8000/polls/2/vote/
>
> Django Version:   1.4 Exception Type: ValueError Exception Value: 
>   invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'on' Exception
>   Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py
>   in get_prep_value, line 537

and here is my polls/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',

```
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$','detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$','results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$','vote'),
```

)

and here is project/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
```

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',

```
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$','detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$','results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$','vote'),
```

)

Comment: Please post the entire text of the error message.

Comment: i solved the problem. i forgot a single quote in detail.html which has include my post method.

Comment: How did you solve this problem exactly? I went so far as copy and pasting the entire tutorial from part 4 and am still getting this error?

Comment: Nevermind, I finally figured it out. My urls.py was making the vote return 1/vote/ instead of just "1". Which of course if the number should be an integer, wouldn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll receive this error when you're trying to cast a string to an integer, but the string doesn't really contain any digits:

i.e.

```
number = int(string)
```

From your code, there are three places where I see the use and probable cast of an integer.  When `p=get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)` we're making an assumption that you've correctly passed in an integer as poll_id.  Could you post the urlpattern you're using associated with this view and an example URL?

You also are making an assumption that `request.POST['choice']` will be an integer and can be cast as such.  You aren't catching an exception related to this, so you'll want to check what the value of this entry is.  I would add in a few other checks for this part:

```
if request.method=="POST":
    choice = request.POST.get('choice', None)
    if choice is not None:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=choice)
...
```

These two stand out the most.

Please post your urlpattern and more of the error message you were getting (such as which specific line is throwing your exception).

Comment: thank you. now i am gonna check my urls.py and back here again.

Comment: Can't you have a non-integer as the slug?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I had the same error, the problem as explained by @cianof was in the template polls/detail.html and in others templates. The error occurs when you paste the code from the tutorial and you have 80 character of margin in your editor.

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice {{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{
choice.id }}" />
```

This will not works because choice.id is close to the braces `{{choice.id }}`, you should always leave a space between: `{{ choice.id }}`

About the casting answer posted by @garromark, I can't say anything, I'm new in Python and Django cooding.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error too.

My my case it I had a typo in my form template. Double check the poll detail template (“polls/detail.html”) for typos.

Comment: Yes, I had a typo in my `detail.html` as well (I had `values` instead of `value`)

Comment: I had valule instead of value!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error occurred. I found out what was wrong, turns out it was just some little details:
First,In my 'polls/detail.html' template, there is an input:

`<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice {{forloop.counter}}" value="{{choice.id}}"/>` I had `{{choice_id}}` before that's why it didn't get the value.

Second, another error said my 'polls/result.html' was not found, then I went into this template I found a stupid mistake:

`<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>`

Inside the  tag, I had 'polls.detail', no wonder why the template was not found. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was receive similar error. Problem was hidden here:

```
def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question: question'})
```